# Redux subscribe seems to not be working and for that my header and footer are not displayed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am working on a React application using Redux for state management. In my layout component, I am trying to display the header and the footer only if there is a user, but I am facing an issue where the they both are not displayed.
I understand that it's because the user is still null, but I can find a way to solve it, tried also subscribe, but no changes.

Here's a simplified version of my Layout component:

```
import Routing from "../Routing/Routing";
import "./Layout.css";
import { NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { authStore } from "../../redux/redux";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import UserModel from "../../../models/UserModel";

function Layout(): JSX.Element {
    const { pathname } = useLocation()
    const hideHeaderPaths: string[] = ['/login']

    const [user, setUser] = useState<UserModel>();
    console.log(user)

    useEffect(() => {
        setUser(authStore.getState().user);

        const unsubscribe = authStore.subscribe(() => {
            const updatedUser = authStore.getState().user
            setUser(updatedUser);
            alert("Change")
        });
        
        setUser(authStore.getState().user);

        return () => unsubscribe();

    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="Layout" style={{ display: hideHeaderPaths.includes(pathname) ? "block" : "grid" }}>
            {!hideHeaderPaths.includes(pathname) && user  && <header><p>{`${user.firstName}  ${user.lastName}`}  |<NavLink to={"/logout"}>Logout</NavLink> </p></header>}
            <main>
                {/* <Main /> */}
                <Routing />
            </main>
            {!hideHeaderPaths.includes(pathname) && <footer>this is the footer</footer>}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

Could anyone please help me understand why the user information is not displayed correctly on the initial render?

I have also tried removing the conditional rendering for the user in the header and footer, but I still face the same problem. The user's first name and last name appear as undefined on the initial render.

To better explain what's going on, I'm tossing in the code for my Redux:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import UserModel from '../../models/UserModel';
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

export class AuthState {
    public token: string = null;
    public user: UserModel = null;

    public constructor() {
        this.token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        if (this.token) {
            const container: { user: UserModel } = jwtDecode(this.token)
            this.user = container.user
            console.log(this.user)

        }
    }
}

export enum AuthActionType {
    register = "register",
    login = "login",
    logout = "logout"
}



export interface AuthAction {
    type: AuthActionType,
    payload?: any

}

export function authReducer(currentState = new AuthState(), action: AuthAction): AuthState {

    const newState = { ...currentState }

    switch (action.type) {

        case AuthActionType.login:
        case AuthActionType.register:
            newState.token = action.payload;
            localStorage.setItem("token", newState.token);
            break;

        case AuthActionType.logout:
            newState.token = null;
            newState.user = null;
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            console.log(newState.user)
            break;

    }
    return newState
}


export const authStore = createStore(authReducer)
```

After clicking Login button, the next function is triggered:

```
async function sendCredentials(credentials: CredentialsModel): Promise<void> {
    try {

        const result = await axios.post('http://localhost:4004/api/auth/login', credentials)

        const token = result.data

        localStorage.setItem("token", token)    

        authStore.dispatch({type: AuthActionType.login, payload: token})

    } catch (error:any) {

        console.log(error.message)
        throw error

    }



}
```

Comment: `authStore.getState()` is a bit of an uncommon pattern for using redux state in function components. Have you tried `connect()` or `useSelector` from redux toolkit? Those two are the recommended methods to get redux state as props into components. Subscribing and then unsubscribing to the store is not really necessary if you only care about rendering a username in your component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out the fix. It's a bit weird because it looks like this piece of code is doing a double take in redux, first in the state itself and second time on the switch function. I threw in these two lines:

```
const container: { user: UserModel } = jwtDecode(action.payload); 
newState.user = container.user;
```

below the AuthActionType.login/AuthActionType.register case and it works like a charm!

Comment: Yes, I think that will also be sufficient enough to update the state reference *and* get the `user` property updated.

Answer (score 0):

Important thing to remember: `useEffect` is asynchronous and will always happen after the initial render.

In your case, React renders your component first time and uses the initial state you provided in `useState`. You provided nothing, which is basically an alias for `undefined`. That's basically the reason why you see `undefined`. Then after some time `useEffect` is called and it updates the state with the correct data.

I suggest making the following change:

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState<UserModel>(authStore.getState().user);
```

This way you will reach to the store as soon as component gets mounted and user will be defined at the time of initial render.

Comment: Hey, I gave your solution a shot, but no luck. Even after tweaking things as you suggested, the 'user' is still null when the component gets rendered

Comment: If so, then I guess your user is set asynchronously and at the time this component renders it’s really undefined in the store. Could you share the code responsible for populating this property?

Comment: Of course! I have just added my redux, and the function that immediatelly triggered when user insert his credentials and click Login button :)

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` hook runs at ***the end*** of the render cycle, so any side-effects won't be available on the initial render.

This is not how React components subscribe to a Redux store. Use the `useSelector` hook and select the appropriate state. ***Don't*** use `store.subscribe` and duplicated local state.

Example:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"; // <-- import hook
import Routing from "../Routing/Routing";
import "./Layout.css";
import UserModel from "../../../models/UserModel";

function Layout(): JSX.Element {
  const { pathname } = useLocation()
  const hideHeaderPaths: string[] = ['/login']

  const user = useSelector(state => state.user); // <-- subscribe to user state

  return (
    <div
      className="Layout"
      style={{ display: hideHeaderPaths.includes(pathname) ? "block" : "grid" }}
    >
      {!hideHeaderPaths.includes(pathname) && user && (
        <header>
          <p>
            {user.firstName} {user.lastName} |
            <NavLink to="/logout">Logout</NavLink>
          </p>
        </header>
      )}
      <main>
        {/* <Main /> */}
        <Routing />
      </main>
      {!hideHeaderPaths.includes(pathname) && (
        <footer>this is the footer</footer>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

When the store is created the `authReducer` is the only reducer passed to `createStore`

```js
export const authStore = createStore(authReducer);
```

So the reducer's state ***is*** the store value. `state.user` is the `AuthState.user` property. The problem here is that a new `AuthState` object is created only once when the `authReducer` function is instantiated, e.g. `currentState = new AuthState()`, and the `login` and `register` actions only mutate the `token` property.

```js
export class AuthState {
  public token: string = null;   // <-- initially null
  public user: UserModel = null; // <-- initially null

  public constructor() {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (this.token) {
      const container: { user: UserModel } = jwtDecode(this.token);
      this.user = container.user;
      console.log(this.user);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
const newState = { ...currentState }

switch (action.type) {
  case AuthActionType.login:
  case AuthActionType.register:
    newState.token = action.payload; // <-- only token property is updated
    localStorage.setItem("token", newState.token);
    break;

  ...
```

`newState.user` is still `null`. The `user` property is only set when the `AuthState` `constructor` is invoked, e.g. when calling `new AuthState()`.

To fix this I believe you could set the new token into localStorage from `sendCredentials` like it already is, and update the `login` and `register` actions to create a ***new*** `AuthState` object reference so the constructor runs and sets the correct `user` property.

```js
const newState = { ...currentState }

switch (action.type) {
  case AuthActionType.login:
  case AuthActionType.register:
    return new AuthState(); // <-- sets token and user properties

  ...
```

It's generally not recommended to store class objects in a Redux store though. An improvement would be to store a plain object with the properties, and shallow copy the current state into the next state when necessary.

Example:

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import UserModel from '../../models/UserModel';
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

type AuthState = {
  token: string | null;
  user: UserModel | null
};

// Read/compute the initial state value from localStorage
const token = localStorage.getItem("token") ?? null;
const user = token
  ? (jwtDecode(token) as { user: UserModel }).user
  : null;

const initialState: AuthState = {
  token,
  user,
};

export enum AuthActionType {
  register = "register",
  login = "login",
  logout = "logout"
}

export interface AuthAction {
  type: AuthActionType,
  payload?: any
}
```

```js
export function authReducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: AuthAction
): AuthState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AuthActionType.login:
    case AuthActionType.register:
       const token = action.payload;
       const user = token
         ? (jwtDecode(token) as { user: UserModel }).user
         : null;
       localStorage.setItem("token", token);
       return { token, user };

    case AuthActionType.logout:
       localStorage.removeItem("token");
       return { token: null, user: null };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const authStore = createStore(authReducer)
```

Comment: Thanks! where did this state came from? 
const user = useSelector(state => state.user) <---
state.user give me nothing

Comment: @RavidGoren `state.user` is based your code selecting a user state, e.g. `authStore.getState().user`. `state` is the current state of the Redux store, it's passed to the selector function `state => state.user` that is passed to the `useSelector` hook. If `state.user` is incorrect then check your reducer path used when the store was created. If you need further help with this then please edit your post to include where you combined your reducers and created the store object, and where you are providing the store value to the app.

Comment: Hey there, I have just added the redux code, thanks!

Comment: @RavidGoren Thanks for the additional details. I've updated my answer, please do check it out when you've time.

Comment: I totally appreciate your hustle in trying to help out. Feel free to check out what I came up with. Turns out, there were just two lines standing between me and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the initial state of the user variable in your component's state. When you first render the component, the user state is undefined and you try to access its properties (firstName and lastName), which results in "undefined" values ​​being displayed.
You can specify an initial default value for the user state. Set it to null and then check if the user exists before accessing its properties.

```
import Routing from "../Routing/Routing";
import "./Layout.css";
import { NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { authStore } from "../../redux/redux";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import UserModel from "../../../models/UserModel";

function Layout(): JSX.Element {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const hideHeaderPaths: string[] = ['/login'];

  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserModel | null>(null); // Set initial state to null

  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(authStore.getState().user);

    const unsubscribe = authStore.subscribe(() => {
      const updatedUser = authStore.getState().user;
      setUser(updatedUser);
    });

   
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Layout" style={{ display: hideHeaderPaths.includes(pathname) ? "block" : "grid" }}>
      {!hideHeaderPaths.includes(pathname) && user && (
        <header>
          <p>{user.firstName} {user.lastName} | <NavLink to={"/logout"}>Logout</NavLink></p>
        </header>
      )}

      <main>
        {/* <Main /> */}
        <Routing />
      </main>

      {!hideHeaderPaths.includes(pathname) && <footer>this is the footer</footer>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

Here the initial user state is null and the component will only try to access the firstName and LastName properties if the user value is not null. This should prevent "undefined" values ​​from being shown on initial rendering. Once the Redux store updates the user information,
the component will be updated again.

Comment: Hey, I gave your solution a shot, but no luck. Even after tweaking things as you suggested, the 'user' is still null when the component gets rendered